# Which robots.txt for forwarded subdomain?

Tags: subdomain, robots.txt

In theory I have two subdomains set up in my hosting:

`subdomain1.mydomain.com`

`subdomain2.mydomain.com`

`subdomain2` has a `CNAME` record pointing to an external service.

`mydomain.com` has a `robots.txt` that allows indexing everything.

`subdomain2.mydomain.com` has a `robots.txt` that allows indexing nothing due to the `CNAME` record.

If I set up a forward from `subdomain1.mydomain.com` to `subdomain2.mydomain.com`, which `robots.txt` would be used if accessing a link to `subdomain1.mydomain.com`? Does the domain forward work in the same way as a `CNAME` record when it comes to `robots.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your server setup.

Take the following config, for example:

```
server {
    server_name subdomainA.example.com;
    listen 80;

    return 302 http://subdomainB.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

In this case, we're redirecting *everything* from `subdomainA.example.com` to `subdomainB.example.com`. This will include your `robots.txt` file.

However, if your configuration is set up to only redirect certain parts, your `robots.txt` file will only be redirected if it's on your list. This would be the case if you were redirecting only, say, `/someFolder`.

Note that if you don't return a 302 but just use a different root (e.g. `subdomainA` and `subdomainB` are different subdomains but serve the same content), your `robots.txt` content will be determined by the root directory.

So, therefore, if I'm understanding your config correctly, `subdomain1` will use the the `robots.txt` from `subdomain2`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although, I don't understand anything of what you said other than the last sentence which does appear to answer my question :)

Comment: @Lyall It *should* work like that, but it would be best if you could post your config (if you can) or similar so that we can make sure.

Comment: Do you know where I can find the config? My hosting is with 1&1 so I'm not sure if I have access. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The challenge you're running into is you're looking at things from the standpoint of whatever software you're trying to configure, but search engines and other robots only see the document they load from a URL (just like any other user with a web browser would). That is, search engines will try to load `http://subdomain1.mydomain.com/robots.txt` and `http://subdomain2.mydomain.com/robots.txt`, and it's up to you (through configuring whatever software your server is running) to ensure that those are in fact serving what you want.

A CNAME is just a way to add a redirection when loading what IP a browser should look at to resolve a domain name. A robot will use it when resolving the name to find out the "real" IP to connect to, but it doesn't have any further bearing on what the `GET /robots.txt` request does once it connects to the server.

In terms of "forwarding", that term can mean different things, so you'd need to know what a browser or robot would receive when it requested the page. If it's doing a 301 or 302 redirection to send the client to another URL, you'll probably get different results from different search engines on how they may honor that, particularly if it's being redirected to an entirely different domain. I probably would try to avoid it, just because a lot of robots are poorly written. Some search engines have tools to help you determine how their crawlers are reading your `robots.txt` URLs, such as [Google's tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598).